# How to fill a List of Lists?

Tags: java, arraylist

I create a list of lists like this:

```
List<List> tmp = new ArrayList<List>(2);
```

Then I'd like to insert 10 to first sub-list as follows:

```
tmp.get(0).add(10);
```

However, I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
>       at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)

What is the source of error and how can I overcome it ?

Comment: "_I create a list of lists like this_" You didn't actually make a list of lists, just simply a list.

Comment: `tmp.size()`.....

Comment: @takendarkk - Semantically speaking, they *did* create a list of lists, it just happens to currently have length 0.

Comment: Ya, I guess it depends on how you look at it. I see that as just a list - once something is inside _then_ it is a list of something.

Comment: TL;DR - the constructor you're calling creates an empty list with initial capacity of 2 items. To avoid the error, add some lists to the outer list.

Comment: Don't use raw or rare types like `List<List>`!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've created an empty list with initial capacity of `2` (i.e. the internal representation of the list won't be resized until you've added 2 elements to it and are adding the third).

Then you try to get the first element from the empty list. Naturally this won't work. You need to first `add()` as many inner lists (presumably 2) as you want, and *then* fill those inner lists.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You have not initialized the inner list. That's the reason you are getting the error.

Following code will initialize each of the inner list.

```
int initialCapacity=2;
List<List> tmp = new ArrayList<List>(initialCapacity);
for(int i = 0; i < initialCapacity; i++)
     tmp.add(new ArrayList());
```

Comment: That for loop won't resolve anything, as it iterates (or rather doesn't iterate) the empty list.

Comment: Yeah you still have to call `set()` or something similar on the outer list to actually put something in it.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: And ... it still won't work, because the size() is initially zero.

Comment: @AndyThomas I guess if I hard-code the size, it will work, e.g. nSize = 2 and then do this iteration.

Comment: @santosh-patil It does. Thank you :)

Comment: Downvoting for the use of a rare type.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added anything to the list yet. Declaring a List of any type with an initial capacity of 2 doesn't automatically populate that. You have to do that first.

Comment: The list does not have size 2 - it has an initial *capacity* of 2. The initial size is zero.